# C++ Dynamic float dies in the constructer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i need a float array in my field class.
Everything worked fine, and now i wanted to make my heighmap a bit more dynamic.

I just figured out that it dies while im doing this:

```
*highMap = new float[mapWidth];
for (int x = 0; x<GFX_Rx; x++)
{
    *highMap[x]=30;
}
```

and highmap in the headerfile

```
float* highMap[];
```

Thank you

Comment: `highMap` is declared as an array of `float *` with no size. If you want to dynamically allocate, drop the `[]` on declaration and the extra `*` on usage. But generally `std::vector` or other container classes are a better way to go if possible.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? In C++, `float* highMap[];` is a compile-time error, and it should be reported as such by your compiler, so I'm surprised it compiles for you.

Comment: Also consider checking the bounds of your loop, as from your code it is not clear if the size of the allocated memory is compatible with 'GFX_Rx' variable

Comment: it shouldn't compile at all, you can't declare an array with dynamic size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code. First you can't declare an array with dynamic size, it shouldn't even compile. Second, you can't dereference a pointer without knowing it points to some valid location, you'll get seg fault.

If you don't want to use std::vector, you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

const int mapWidth = 5;
float** highMap;
int GFX_Rx=5;

int main() 
{
    highMap = new float*[mapWidth];
    for (int x = 0; x<GFX_Rx; x++)
    {
        highMap[x]=new float(30);
    }
}
```